# How can postgres change from unix epoch time with miliseconds to timestamptz?

Tags: postgresql

I am using the below postgres sql to convert from unix epoch time to timestamp.

```
select to_timestamp(1608816600) at time zone 'UTC';
```

It works when the epoch time does not contain milliseconds but when it contains milliseconds, it does not work. The below query:

```
select to_timestamp(1611150788148) at time zone 'UTC';
```

returns:

[image]

However it should be **Wed Jan 20 2021 13:53:08** with some milliseconds. Source: https://currentmillis.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.15.5.2.2.35.1.1.1) `to_timestamp()` expects a "**seconds** since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00" - but it allows fractional values.

If you want to specify milliseconds you need to divide your value by 1000

```
select to_timestamp(1611150788148::double precision/1000) at time zone 'UTC';
```

---

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(1611150788148/1000.0) at time zone 'UTC', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3');

to_char                
-----------------------
2021-01-20 13:53:08.148
```

Comment: So the miliseconds part would always be 148ms. I am not a 100% sure how the intricacies of calculating epoch time work but does the given epoch value signify 148 ms?

Comment: @Mistu4u: yes it does (but you need to cast the value to `double` otherwise it's an integer division. This is one of the many reasons why you shouldn't store "epoch" values in the database to begin with.

Comment: An Interesting read: [Epoch Mania](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/).